# How to edit the Checkout button to Order Now

Tags: php, magento

I need to change the text of the checkout button which is viewed once hovered on the cart if any product is their in the cart, I need to rename it as **Order Now** instead of **Checkout**.

Please do suggest me the answer...

Below is the link to the image...
[Click here to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLE73.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update `Checkout` word to `Order Now` ONLY in the Header Cart => Mini Cart, do the following:

**Assuming** you are using the RWD theme, navigate to *app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml*

**Line no: 94 & 95** From:

```
<a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Checkout')) ?>" class="button checkout-button" href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>">
   <?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>
</a>
```

Update to:

```
<a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Order Now')) ?>" class="button checkout-button" href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>">
   <?php echo $this->__('Order Now') ?>
</a>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

you can simply locate the template of that block and change the text. You can locate the template by using template path hints under

> **system->configuration->developer** and **set show template path hints to yes**

and than on front-end you will be able to see the template file path on browser and you can easily change the text than.

thanks and let me know if there is any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can change simply by admin go to this path

***Admin->system->configuration->developer->( click )Translate Inline and yes in ' Enabled for Frontend'*** save config

Refres your frontend and change your text then submit

Solve your problem......